# Splitting a string field to create 2 records in a table

Tags: sql, string, sql-server-2008, split

I have a table XX with the following data:

```
REF        Part      DESC                                              Model
1    6200050     Screw, #10-12 x 1/2" Pan HD                    UC-24C UC-24CI Cosmetic
2    7006474     Kickplate, Silver Svce                     UC-24C UC-24CI Cosmetic
3    7002139     Cover, Unit Svce                           UC-24C UC-24CI Cosmetic
4    6201270     Screw, #8-18 x 5/8" PH PN SS-Gnd               UC-24C UC-24CI Cosmetic
6    7016528     Anti Tip Bracket - Svce - 23-7/8"              UC-24C UC-24CI Cosmetic
7    6200780     Screw, #10-24 x 1/2" PH Hex Washer             UC-24C UC-24CI Cosmetic
```

What I need to do is split the Model field between the two model numbers in the field, creating a new record for each model number, with all other data being the same, and leaving the extended data (the word 'Cosmetic') in the model field on each record.

Comment: The numbers of individual models is always two ?

Comment: It is. I will be targeting the specific models to modify.

Comment: is the extended data always a single word (and always present)? In other words, will there always be three whitespaces in the field? If so, I can give an example of splitting on that field.

Comment: No, Nicholai. There may be more than one word in the extended data.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little piece of SQL that will break up your "model number".  You may be able to use it as part of a procedure to do what you are trying to do...

```
declare @s varchar(255)
declare @m1 varchar(255)
declare @m2 varchar(255)
declare @p varchar(255)

set @s = 'UC-24C UC-24CI Cosmetic'

SET @m1 = SUBSTRING(@s, 0, CHARINDEX(' ',@s))
SET @s = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@s, LEN(@m1 + ' ') + 1, LEN(@s))))
SET @m2 = SUBSTRING(@s, 0, CHARINDEX(' ',@s))
SET @p = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@s, LEN(@m2 + ' ') + 1, LEN(@s))))

SET @m1 = @m1 + ' ' + @p
SET @m2 = @m2 + ' ' + @p

select @m1,@m2
```

results in this:

```
UC-24C Cosmetic UC-24CI Cosmetic
```

Answer (score 0):

The following [**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5868c/55/1) example demonstrates how this can be done with the following:

```
INSERT INTO XXX (Ref, Part, Description, Model)
SELECT Ref, Part, Description, 
Left(Model,CHARINDEX(' ', Model)) 
    + Right(Model,Len(Model)-CHARINDEX(' ', Model, CHARINDEX(' ', Model) +1)) 
FROM XXX;

UPDATE XXX SET 
Model = Right(Model,Len(Model)-CHARINDEX(' ', Model))
WHERE CHARINDEX(' ', Model, CHARINDEX(' ', Model) +1)<>0
```

If your `Ref` field is a auto primary key, then just don't include that field in the INSERT statement.